# SlideToggle doesn't work. I have read other similar questions but didn't find out my answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $(".answer_exp").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">answer</button>
<div class="answer_exp" >
   //some code
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out,please?

Comment: After the update your code should work

Comment: No, still not working!

Comment: Toggle works but slideToggle not working

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: No, i haven't got any error

Comment: I have added the executable code snippet. Please run and see how the code works with `slideToggle()`....

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm wondering why it doesn't work in my project

Comment: Hide(), toggle() and show() all work but slideToggle and fadeToggle not.